# Can I use QueryPerformanceCounter to measure single draw or compute call performance?

Tags: opengl, gpu, performance

I know I can use `QueryPerformanceCounter` for measure time for whole single frame. But can I when it comes to OpenGL draw or compute call?

I always assumed that, as on the diagram, CPU waits for GPU to finish so timer would measure approximate time or am I wrong?

[image]

As seen in code:

```
glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
timer->startCounter();      
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
estimatedRenderTime = timer->getCounter();
```

or

```
timer->startCounter();
glDispatchCompute(width, height, 1);
estimatedRenderTime = timer->getCounter();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That diagram includes a CPU block titled "wait for GPU". I do not see the part of your code that includes an equivalent command.

Furthermore, even if it did include `glFinish`/`glClientWaitSync`/etc, there is no guarantee that the CPU time in any way relates to how much time the GPU spent processing it. `glFinish` might block on a mutex, thus ending the thread's timeslice. Which means that the thread will start up sometime after that mutex is released. How long after? Who knows, but your `QueryPerformanceCounter` call will include that time.

If you want to measure GPU time, you should use tools that actually *measure GPU time*. For example, [timer queries](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries). You bracket some commands with `glBeginQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED, queryObject)` and `glEndQuery(GL_TIME_ELAPSED)`. Then you can [read the result after some time has elapsed](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Query_retrieval). Like maybe next frame.

And unlike `glFinish`, this will not absolutely murder your performance ;)

Comment: Yeah I expected such answer. Wait for GPU - I mean that draw call as any other function returns after its finishes work, in this case let's say - ordered work. Yeah there is some confusion here.

Comment: @narthex: "*returns after its finishes work*" That all depends on how you define "its work". The "work" of a draw call is to drop a token into the GPU's command stream. And sometimes not even that much. In all likelihood, by the time that function returns, [nothing has even *started* to render, let alone finished](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization).

Comment: _OpenGL Rendering Commands are assumed to be asynchronous._ I feel like noob now.